Prove $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ is totally disconnected in $S^{1}$.
I'm trying to prove $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ is totally disconnected.
I know $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are totally disconnected, and the quotient is a torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = S^{1}$. But is a quotient of a totally disconnected group by a totally disconnected subgroup automatically totally disconnected?

For any distinct $x,y\in\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ you can find disjoint open sets $U_1\ni x,U_2\ni y$ such that $U_1\cup U_2=\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}
$. That's the exact same argument you'd use for $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.
ADDED REMARK: If $S$ is a totally disconnected space, any subset of $S$ is totally disconnected too. So, what you're really asking is whether there exists a topological group $G$ that is totally disconnected such that some group quotient of it is not.
And I would say, look at the positive rational numbers with the usual topology, and let the group operation be multiplication. Let $K$ be the set of positive rationals generated by all primes except $2$.
$\mathbb{Q}^+/K$ is connected. That's because $K$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $2\times K$ and $4\times K$ and $\frac{1}{2}\times K$ and $\frac{1}{4}\times K$ etcetera are all dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This means that any given open neighbourhood of $\mathbb{Q}^+$ will intersect with every coset of $K$.

For quotients of totally disconnected groups by closed normal subgroups, see here.
